# Matplotlib: scatter color always blue

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
ax2.scatter(Px, Py, Pz,color = 'red',facecolor='red',edgecolor='red',s=60)
```

but when it is plotted always shows the scatter dots in blue color, the only color that I can change is the edge color. What is happening?

Comment: @Goyo I've change 'color=red' to 'c=red' and it works for me, but might be a bug. Thanks for replying

Comment: The explanation could be also in the code you are actualy running. The code you posted raises a TypeError, both the question and the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem. I changed the code to:

```
 ax2.scatter(Px, Py, Pz,c ='red',edgecolor='red',s=60)
```

and it worked.